# inter arrival time ( continuous exponential distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, queueing-theory, exponential-distribution

The customers arrive at store with exponentially distributed interarrival times with a
mean of 30 minutes.
 What is the probability that interarrival time between two successive customers is 2 hours or more?

**My attempt:**
2 customers arrive every hour, therefore λ=2.

P(T≥2)=∫ λ^(-λt) dt   ( where $λ=2$, upperbound is infinity, and lowerbound is 2).This gives an answer of=$0.018$

however the answer in the answer key is $0.18$ can someone tell me what I did wrong.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The CDF of exponential distribution is $F_T(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$. If described in the unit of hours, we have $\lambda^{-1}=0.5$ and $\lambda=2$. The question asks for $\Pr(T>2)$ which is given by $1-F_T(2)$ or $e^{(-2)(2)}=0.018$, and your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it.I would be grateful if you took your time to look at another question I posted.

http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2053310/386492